ASP.NET Framework : Error copying packageSeverity code description project file line suppression state
I have my ASP.NET on .NET 4.8 Soap service .asmx in this folder in Visual Studio 2022:
C:\Trustedpath\all_Projects\MyProject\MySoapService

It builds, but when I tried to publish, I got this error:

Publish has encountered an error.
Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp725F.tmp"

Then in that path I got:
25/07/2024 4:19:41
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

The Visual Studio error list shows:

Error
Copying file packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll to C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\AppService--1853148479\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll failed. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\AppService--1853148479\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'


According to the error message you listed, it is likely that when setting the file path, you did not consider that the file path during publish is inconsistent with that during debugging.
You need to deal with the error messages listed in the Output Window of Visual Studio
In addition, based on the .NET framework version, you could upgrade Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset(In NuGet) if it not the latest version.
